# Let $X,Y$ and $Z$ be subspaces of a vector space $W$ with dimension $n$. Show that if $dim(X)+dim(Y)+dim(Z)>2n$ then $X \cap Y \cap Z \neq \{0\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W$ be a vector space with $\dim W = n < \infty$ and let $X,Y$ and $Z$ be a subspaces of $W$. How can i prove that if

$$\dim(X) + \dim(Y) + \dim(Z) > 2n \ \implies X \cap Y \cap Z \ne \{0\}. $$

I tried using "Grassmanns formula", but still couldn't find the right solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that:
$$
\dim(Y\cap Z)=\dim(Y)+\dim(Z)-\dim(Y+Z)>(2n-\dim(X))-n
$$
(since $\dim(Y+Z)\leq n$ and $\dim(X)+\dim(Y)+\dim(Z)>2n$)

Therefore $\dim(X)+\dim(Y\cap Z)\geq n+1$ and so
$$
\dim(X\cap Y\cap Z) = \dim(X)+\dim(Y\cap Z) - \dim(X+(Y\cap Z)) \geq 1
$$
So $X\cap Y\cap Z\neq 0$

Answer (score 0):

Lets first start with a small leamma.

---

***Lemma*** *Let $X,Y\subset W$ subspaces of the vector space $W$ with dimension $n$, such that $\dim(X)+\dim(Y)>n$. Then the vector space $X\cap Y$ has at least a dimension of $\dim(X)+\dim(Y)-n$.*

Proof. Let $y_k$ for $k=1,\dots,\dim(Y)$ form a basis of $Y$. W.l.o.g we can assume that there is some $r\in \{1,\dots,\dim(Y)\}$ such that $y_k\in X$ iff  $k\leq r$,i.e. we sort our basis $y_k$. Then for $Y':=$span$\{y_k|r<k<\dim(Y)\}$ we have $Y'\cap X = \{0\}$. Thus we have $\dim(Y'\oplus X)=\dim(X)+\dim(Y)-r\leq n$, since both spaces are linear independent and both are subspace of $W$. Further, we notice that $r=\dim(X\cap Y)$, hence it follows $\dim(X)+\dim(Y)-n\leq\dim(X\cap Y)$. $\Box$

---

We can now solve the exercise. We first observe
$$\dim(X)+\dim(Y)>2n-\dim(Z)\geq n,$$
hence applying the lemma above we obtain
$$\dim(X\cap Y)\geq \dim(X)+\dim(Y)-n>n-\dim(Z), $$
while we have used the first inequality. Then by rearanging we have
$$\dim(X\cap Y)+\dim(Z)>n.$$
Thus, we can apply the lemma once more and finally get
$$\dim(X\cap Y\cap Z)\geq \dim(X\cap Y)+\dim(Z)-n\geq \underbrace{\dim(X)+\dim(Y)+\dim(Z)}_{>2n}-2n>0.$$
Therefore, the dimension of the intersection as at least dimension 1 and with that we have $X\cap Y\cap Z\neq \{0\}$.